# Conditional remote: true depending on validation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form in a partial `_donation_form.html.haml` which is rendered as a modal. I am trying to do the following:

1. If the record can be saved, redirect to a different page
2. Else render the modal with validation error messages.

Everything works except that when the record is invalid, redirection to a different page does not work.

I have the following in `_donation_form.html.haml` which is rendered as a modal.

```
= bootstrap4_form_for([:admin, donation], remote: true, html: { multipart: true, id: 'manual_donations', autocomplete: 'nope'}) do |f|
 # form with submit_button which calls `create` action of `donations_controller.rb`
```

This is my `new.js.erb` which renders the above modal:

```
$('#newDonation').modal('hide');
$('#newDonation, .modal-backdrop').remove();
$('body').append("<%= j render partial: 'donation_modal' %>");
$('#newDonation').modal('show')
```

I added `remote: true` in `_donation_form.html.haml` as when the validation fails I want to render `new.js.erb`.

Following is `donations_controller.rb`:

```
def index; end

def new
  donation.cause_id = cause.id if entity.causes.count == 1
  donation.event_id = params[:event_id]
end

def create
    # some code
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        donation.recorded_offline!
        respond_with(:admin, donation, :location => admin_donations_path)
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      render :new
    end
end
```

When I click on submit button of the modal with a valid record, page does not redirect and I get the following message on console:

```
Processing by Admin::DonationsController#index as JS
-----------
No template found for Admin::DonationsController#index, rendering head :no_content
```

I have the view `index.html.haml` under `app/views/admin/donations/`. When I remove `remote: true` from `_donation_form.html.haml`, redirection works just fine. However, in that case rendering `new.js.erb` with validation error messages does not work. I am not really sure how to tackle this situation.

Comment: Where is this `index.html.haml` located? It has to be under `app/views/admin/donations/`

Comment: It is under app/views/admin/donations/. Redirection works when I remove `remote: true` from the form